# Select two or more consecutive rows based on a criteria using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-mining

I have a data set like this:

```
user        time              city    cookie    index
A        2019-01-01 11.00     NYC     123456      1
A        2019-01-01 11.12     CA      234567      2 
A        2019-01-01 11.18     TX      234567      3
B        2019-01-02 12.19     WA      456789      4 
B        2019-01-02 12.21     FL      456789      5
B        2019-01-02 12.31     VT      987654      6
B        2019-01-02 12.50     DC      157890      7
A        2019-01-03 09:12     CA      123456      8
A        2019-01-03 09:27     NYC     345678      9
A        2019-01-03 09:34     TX      123456      10
A        2019-01-04 09:40     CA      234567      11
```

In this data set I want to compare and select two or more **consecutive** which fit the following criteria:

1. User should be same
2. Time difference should be less than 15 mins
3. Cookie should be different

So if I apply the filter I should get the following data:

```
user        time              city    cookie    index
A        2019-01-01 11.00     NYC     123456      1
A        2019-01-01 11.12     CA      234567      2 
B        2019-01-02 12.21     FL      456789      5
B        2019-01-02 12.31     VT      987654      6
A        2019-01-03 09:12     CA      123456      8
A        2019-01-03 09:27     NYC     345678      9
A        2019-01-03 09:34     TX      123456      10
```

So, in the above, comparing first two rows(index 1 and 2) satisfy all the conditions above. The next two (index 2 and 3) has same cookie, index 3 and 4 has different user, 5 and 6 is selected and displayed, 6 and 7 has time difference more than 15 mins. 8,9 and 10 fit the criteria but 11 doesnt as the date is 24 hours apart.

How can I solve this using python dataframe? All help is appreciated.

---

**What I have tried:**

I tried creating flags using

> shift()

```
cookiediff=pd.DataFrame(df.Cookie==df.Cookie.shift())
cookiediff.columns=['Cookiediffs']
timediff=pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(df.time) - pd.to_datetime(df.time.shift()))
timediff.columns=['timediff']
mask = df.user != df.user.shift(1)

timediff.timediff[mask] = np.nan
cookiediff['Cookiediffs'][mask] = np.nan
```

Comment: You'll be much more likely to get a good answer if you can show what you've already tried, and where you've gotten stuck.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```py
import numpy as np

#you have inconsistent time delim-just to correct it per your sample data
df["time"]=df["time"].str.replace(":", ".")
df["time"]=pd.to_datetime(df["time"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H.%M")

cond_=np.logical_or(
    df["time"].sub(df["time"].shift()).astype('timedelta64[m]').lt(15) &\
    df["user"].eq(df["user"].shift()) &\
    df["cookie"].ne(df["cookie"].shift()), 
    df["time"].sub(df["time"].shift(-1)).astype('timedelta64[m]').lt(15) &\
    df["user"].eq(df["user"].shift(-1)) &\
    df["cookie"].ne(df["cookie"].shift(-1)), 
)

res=df.loc[cond_]
```

Few points- you need to ensure your `time` column is `datetime` in order to make the 15 minutes condition verifiable.
Then - the final filter (`cond_`) you obtain by comparing each row to the previous one, checking all 3 conditions OR by doing the same, but checking against the next one (otherwise you would just get all the consecutive matching rows, except the first one).

Outputs:

```py
  user                time city  cookie  index
0    A 2019-01-01 11:00:00  NYC  123456      1
1    A 2019-01-01 11:12:00   CA  234567      2
4    B 2019-01-02 12:21:00   FL  456789      5
5    B 2019-01-02 12:31:00   VT  987654      6
7    A 2019-01-03 09:12:00   CA  123456      8
8    A 2019-01-03 09:27:00  NYC  345678      9
9    A 2019-01-03 09:34:00   TX  123456     10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html?#module-re) to isolate the fields and use named groups and the [`groupdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html?#re.Match.groupdict) function to store the value of each field into a dictionary and compare the values from the last dictionary to the current one. So iterate through each line of the dataset with two dictionaries, the current dictionary and the last dictionary, and perform a `re.search()` on each line with the regex pattern string to separate each line into named fields, then compare the value of the two dictionaries.

So, something like:

```py
import re
c_dict=re.search('(?P<user>\w) +(?P<time>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}\.\d{2}) +(?P<city>\w+) +(?P<cookie>\d{6}) +(?P<index>\d+)',s).groupdict()
```

for each line of your dataset. For the first line of your dataset, this would create the dictionary `{'user': 'A', 'time': '2019-01-01 11.00', 'city': 'NYC', 'cookie': '123456', 'index': '1'}`. With the fields isolated, you could easily compare the values of the fields to previous lines if you stored those in another dictionary.